# Get Process for CPU usage in powershell

Tags: powershell

This particular code in Powershell is to generate CPU usage (in percentage) same as the task manager. But, the problem with this one is that it runs for once and for all not continuously.

`Get-Process | Select-Object -Property Name, CPU, $CPUPercent, Description |Sort-Object -Property CPUPercent -Descending`

How do I take the results continuously in mentioned time interval?

Comment: What are you using for $CPUPercent?

Comment: @shadowz1337 How much % of the CPU is being used for the specific process I'd say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is the mentioned time interval? You can take the results continuously using a `do while` loop:

```
do
{
    Get-Process | Select-Object -Property Name, CPU, $CPUPercent, Description |Sort-Object -Property CPUPercent -Descending
    Sleep 1
}
while ($true)
```

**Note**: Im using the Sleep cmdlet to reduce the outputs.